# What is the pythonic way of getting the sub-elements of an element in an xml file

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I tried the following:

```
tree = ET.parse(latestSumocfg)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    if child.tag == "input":
        for granchild in child:
            print(granchild.get('value'))
```

It works but I am sure there is a more elegant solution to this

Answer (score -1):

You can use `findall`:

```
tree = ET.parse(latestSumocfg)
for grandchild in tree.findall('input/*'):
    print(granchild.get('value'))
```

or if you use the ElementTree implementation of `lxml`:

```
tree = lxml.etree.parse(latestSumocfg)
for value in tree.xpath('input/*/@value'):
    print(value)
```